# How to assign an specific warehouse to execute a dashboard view in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a dashboard where some kpis and information regarding the account_usage are displayed.

However, I want to create an specific warehouse to be assigned of the execution of this dashboard.

Does someone know how to achieve this, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's explained [here](hhttps://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-dashboards#using-dashboards). Just search for `Context selector`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a specific warehouse and grant usage of the warehouse to the role that you will use to run the dashboard.

In Snowflake, privileges to use a warehouse are granted to a role, not to an object like a dashboard etc.